# How to upload image without any php script?

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, image-uploading

please tell me can i upload image from iphone without using php or .net script. i found a code of php

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/myappname/uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://www.mycompanywebsite.com/myappname/uploads/{$file}";
}

?>
```

by hitting URL i think image will be uploaded but can i upload without help of server side script?

Waiting for your kind reply
:)

Comment: Upload from iPhone to what?  Your own web server?  Why don't you want to use server-side scripting?  It makes little sense not to, unless I am missing something.

Comment: you need both a form(post, to set headers for the server to understand the request) and server side code(to handle the posted "image" from the form) to upload an image... `by hitting URL` will not work

Comment: Web servers are built for serving content. Accepting content is outside their purview and they hand that job off to scripts. Allowing arbitrary uploads to a server without any sort of control over the process is a horrible security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to upload a photo from the iPhone without using server side script. You could FTP the photo. You would need your server to be an FTP server. Not the most secure thing in the world, but technically all the work is done on the phone side without server side code.

[FTP sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload a file to your server/hosting without PHP. (Or some other server side script).

If that would be possibile I could deface every site on the net